# Fail to connect to camera service in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin app, there is a Custom Camera Renderer. It had [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012073/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-in-xamarin), which [@Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5141991/jai) had resolved.

It solved all the problems, but I wasn't able to use the Front Camera, could only use Rear Camera. He suggested to use `Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);` instead of `Control.Preview = Camera.Open();`

As there are multiple pages, the first two pages has **Rear Camera** enable, and on the last, **Front Camera**. When I choose to Redo (take all the 3 Pictures, and then start again from first page), on the first & second page, app crashes and says, `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Fail to connect to camera service'`. On `Control.Preview = Camera.Open();` it didn't crash (but can't use front camera).

This code works perfectly, but only Rear Camera works. Can't use Front Camera.

```
Control.Preview = Camera.Open();
```

On this Code,  the Front & Rear Camera both works. But It throws an exception `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Fail to connect to camera service'`

```
Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
```

**[Complete Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012073/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-in-xamarin)**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Mobile.App.CameraPreview> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        // Unsubscribe
        cameraPreview.Click -= OnCameraPreviewClicked;
    }
    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        if (Control == null)
        {
            cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
            SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
        }

        Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
        //Control.Preview = Camera.Open();

        e.NewElement.Subscribe += (sender, p) =>
        {
            Control.Subscribe();
        };
        e.NewElement.Unsubscribe += (sender, p) =>
        {
            Control.Unsubscribe();
        };

        // Subscribe
        cameraPreview.Click += OnCameraPreviewClicked;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to set the camera to null before you used it or after you used it.

Comment: u mean to use `Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);` in `if (Control != null) {}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Release the camera after use it.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Mobile.App.CameraPreview> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        // Unsubscribe
        cameraPreview.Click -= OnCameraPreviewClicked;
    }
    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        if (Control == null)
        {
            cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
            SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
        }

        e.NewElement.Subscribe += (sender, p) =>
        {
            Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
            Control.Subscribe();
        };
        e.NewElement.Unsubscribe += (sender, p) =>
        {
            Control.Preview.Release();
            Control.Preview = null;
            Control.Unsubscribe();
        };

        // Subscribe
        cameraPreview.Click += OnCameraPreviewClicked;
    }
}
```

Comment: after clicking a picture `Control.Preview.Realease()` within `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { if (disposing)  { Control.Preview.Release(); } base.Dispose(disposing); }` throws an exception `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: because we have set the Control.Preview = null; now you can check Control.Preview!=null before using it in Dispose method if(disposing) { if(Control.Preview!=null) Control.Preview.Release();}