# Disable Touch on Specific Component on Screen in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Here is the Reproducible Demo**
https://github.com/x0axz/CustomRenderer

In my Xamarin App, there is a Custom Camera Renderer for Android, which is being called from Xaml through `MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "A");`.

**How it works**

By clicking on button, Camera Preview is stopped & then it perform all the processes (take picture, store it etc.). But when I touch the Camera Preview area, then it only stops the preview, does nothing else. Because there is proper event call behind button, and there isn't any behind the Camera Preview area.

**Error**

And after tapping on Camera Preview area, when I click on button, it doesn't find any open camera preview (because earlier by tapping it stopped the preview), so now it throws the `takePicture failed` exception (it's from camera renderer not the button).

**Camera Preview View**

```
<local:CameraPreview
    x:Name="CameraPreview"
    Camera="Rear"/>
```

**Button Code**

```
<Button
    Clicked="Camera_Clicked">
</Button>
```

```
public void Camera_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "A");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        if (error.InnerException != null)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", error.InnerException.Message, "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

**CameraPreviewRenderer.cs**

By tapping the Camera Preview area, the `StopPreview()` get calls in `OnCameraPreviewClicked()`, which stops the preview.

```
public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Mobile.App.CameraPreview, CameraPreview>
{
    CameraPreview cameraPreview;

    public CameraPreviewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Mobile.App.CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
            cameraPreview.Click -= OnCameraPreviewClicked;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
                SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
            }

            e.NewElement.Subscribe += (sender, p) =>
            {
                Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
                Control.Subscribe();
            };
            e.NewElement.Unsubscribe += (sender, p) =>
            {
                Control.Preview.Release();
                Control.Preview = null;
                Control.Unsubscribe();
            };

            // Subscribe
            cameraPreview.Click += OnCameraPreviewClicked;
        }
    }

    void OnCameraPreviewClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cameraPreview.IsPreviewing)
        {
            cameraPreview.Preview.StopPreview();
            cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cameraPreview.Preview.StartPreview();
            cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Control.Preview != null)
            {
                Control.Preview.Release();
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to capture picture even the preview is paused. Is that you trying to do?

Comment: no, I want to disable the touch/click/tap on camera preview area `<local:CameraPreview />`

Comment: Then you can remove the void OnCameraPreviewClicked method in CameraPreviewRenderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent tap on camera Preview , you can remove `OnCameraPreviewClicked`.

Your `CameraPreviewRender` will be like this

```
public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomRenderer.CameraPreview, CustomRenderer.Droid.CameraPreview>
{
    CameraPreview cameraPreview;

    public CameraPreviewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomRenderer.CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {

        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);
                SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
            }

            e.NewElement.Subscribe += (sender, p) =>
            {
                Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);
                Control.Subscribe();
            };
            e.NewElement.Unsubscribe += (sender, p) =>
            {
                Control.Preview.Release();
                Control.Preview = null;
                Control.Unsubscribe();
            };

        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Control.Preview != null)
            {
                Control.Preview.Release();
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur response.. no error but it isn't capturing pictures.. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075447/14139029

Comment: I didnt understand. Now the preview click  will not pause the camera right? So what is the issue currently facing now?

Comment: when I click on button, picture isn't being taken (store in mobile storage).. when I use your code else it's working perfectly

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: my bad, it's working.. @Anand thanks alot :)

Comment: :) Glad to hear. Happy coding

Comment: I add some code in ur answer, it's complete code, it will help others.. again, thanks for helping..